# What are some good strategies for synchronizing in this multi-threaded situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two primary threads.  One spawns new threads and the other listens for results, like so:

```
//Spawner
while(!done) {
    spawnNewProcess(nextId, parameters);

    myListener.listenFor(nextId);

    nextId ++;
}
```

The spawnNewProcess method takes a widely variable amount of time.  When it finishes, it will put a result object into a map that can be accessed by Id.

The listener thread runs like so:

```
//Listener
while(!done) {
    for (int id : toListenFor) {
        if (resultMap.contains(id)) {
            result = resultMap.get(id);

            toListenFor.remove(id);

            process(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't change the spawnNewProcess method, nor how it stores results.  What I want to do is set a maximum limit on how many can be going concurrently.  My first inclination would be to just have a variable track that number.  If the max would be exceeded, then the spawner waits.  When a result comes back, the listener will notify it.  Like this:

```
//Spawner2

AtomicInteger numSpawns = new AtomicInteger(0);
int maxSpawns = 10;

while(!done) {
    if (numSpawns.intValue() >= maxSpawns) {
        this.wait(0);
    }
    numSpawns.getAndIncrement;

    spawnNewProcess(nextId, parameters);

    myListener.listenFor(nextId);

    nextId ++;
}
```

And the Listener be:

```
//Listener2
while(!done) {
    for (int id : toListenFor) {
        if (resultMap.contains(id)) {
            result = resultMap.get(id);

            toListenFor.remove(id);

            numSpawns.getAndDecrement();
            Spawner.notify();

            process(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Will this work?  Are there potential deadlocks that I'm missing? It wouldn't be a huge deal if somehow 11 or 9 spawns were running at the same time instead of 10.  Or is there a much better way that I'm oblivious to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(NUM_MAX_CONCURRENT);

// Spawner
while(!done) {

    sem.acquire(); // added by corsiKa

    spawnNewProcess(nextId, parameters);

    myListener.listenFor(nextId);

    nextId ++;
}

// listener
while(!done) {
    for (int id : toListenFor) {
        if (resultMap.contains(id)) {
            result = resultMap.get(id);

            toListenFor.remove(id);
            sem.release(); // added by corsiKa
            process(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the number of spawners running, use a `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size)`, which will always run no more than a fixed amount of tasks at once. Then wrap the spawning tasks in a `Runnable` and pass them to the `ExecutorService`.

```
while(!done) {
    task = new Runnable() { public void run() {
        spawnNewProcess(nextId, parameters);
    } });

    exec.submit(task);;

    nextId ++;
}
```

To get the results back, use a `SynchronousQueue` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, which will allow you to pass objects between threads without using lower-level concurrency objects.

Comment: Can't.  The spawnNewProcess method actually contains the call to start it's own thread, and I can't modify it.

Comment: then talk to the author :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a huge fan of jumping through hoops to use a crazy API. I usually just fork and rewrite the API. :) That function should really just return a `Runnable`.